# Remove CLRF in the end of text in SSIS

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, char, ssis-2012

I want to remove the CLRF in the END of text with SSIS. For this I am using the derived column with the following expression:

`REPLACE((REPLACE(COLUMN_NAME,"\n","")),"\r","")`

BUT this works in every part of the text, not only in the end of it.

Im having two cases:

1. Remove the CHAR(10) from the END of text
2. Remove the CHAR(13)+CHAR(10) from the END of text

Is is possible to have it work in SSIS with Derived column?

Thank you!

Comment: Not possible with out-of-the-box functions from SQL Server. Unless with lots of other functions like REVERSE and CASE checks. Then again if you are in SSIS consider the power you have there and pass this column into a string manipulation and using REGEX functionality.

Comment: Use a C# script task and you can loop through the file (if huge) and replace line by line.

Comment: i'll piggy back Brad. C# has TrimEnd() you can use which allows you to specify what to trim. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.trimend?view=net-5.0